# Date().timeIntervalSince1970 in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react native app I am setting the `date` using the following:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

In my Swift App im using:

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Is there a function or something I can use in Javascript which is similar to `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` or vice-versa (the data is being stored in firebase cloud storage).

Because im using different formats, messages are not showing in the correct order.

Comment: i think it is `Date().getTime()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Swift method, but could this be related to JS using milliseconds for the time whereas other languages can use seconds? Did you look into the actual values you're getting?

Comment: `timeIntervalSince1970` is the seconds from 1970 to the date. So in javascript, it should be `Date().getTime() / 1000` as the timestamp value is in milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code [timeIntervalSince1970](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970) as per the documentation is the seconds from 1970 to the date.

So a similar function in javascript can be [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), but it returns the milliseconds. so you will have to divide that by 1000

```
new Date().getTime() / 1000
```

also if you are checking of the reverse, you should be multiplying the seconds with 1000 to get the milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) method which returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC, then divide by 1000, like this:

```js
const millis = Date.now();

const time = Math.floor(millis / 1000);

console.log(time);
```